# python - pandas - setting x ticks labels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe =

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dico = OrderedDict({"Cisco" :54496.923851069776,
"Citrix" :75164.2973859488,
"Datacore/veritas/docker/quest" :7138.499540816414,
"Dell / EMC" : 34836.42983441935,
"HPE": 40265.33070005489,
"IBM Hard Ware / IBM services" : 220724.89293359307,
"Microsoft cloud" : 3159.7624999999994,
"Netapp":48898.21721115539,
"Nutanix / Lenovo DCG":38761.815197677075,
"Oracle/Microfocus":100877.21884162886,
"Other brands":13825.151033348895,
"VM Ware":21267.66907692287,
"Veeam / Redhat":5006.715599405339})
```

That I can plot :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dico.values()))
df.index = dico.keys()
ax = df.sort(0).plot.barh()
```

[image]

but I want to format the xtick labels :

```
ax = df.sort_values(0).plot.barh()

new_labels = [str(pow(10,i-1))+"€" if i>0 else str(i) for i, tick_label in enumerate(ax.get_xticklabels())]
print(new_labels)
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

Giving :

['0', '1€', '10€', '100€', '1000€', '10000€']
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxPtV.png)

Why don't I get 20 000 in the list of the new labels ? 
Why the 10 000 it self is not displayed ?

Comment: You don't get 20000 because you are creating powers of 10 as `pow(10,i-1)`. It is mathematically  not possibly from this equation

Comment: @Bazingaa please put your comment as an answer. Since you answered this question perfectly.

Comment: Ok, if you say so :) I did

Comment: I don't get it :-/ the equation is : str(pow(10,i-1))+"€" if i>0 else str(i)

Comment: Your `enumerate` returns `i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. When `i=0`, you get `str(i)` which means `0`. But then for `i=1,2,3,4`, `i` is always `>0` and hence you just create powers of 10 using `pow`

Comment: yes, so there is always a pow mathematically possible, no ?

Comment: How can `10^i`, `i` being a positive integer (index from `enumerate`) ever give `20000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get `20000` because you are creating powers of `10` as `pow(10,i-1)`. It is mathematically not possibly from this equation. Moreover, `10000` is not displayed because you just use `ax.set_xticklabels` to reset the labels of the already existing xticks. Since you have only 5 major ticks in your first plot, you only create 5 labels as 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000 as per your definition.

To get what you want, just replace the last three lines of your code (after plotting) by:

```
locs = ax.get_xticks()
labels = [ '{}{}'.format(int(i), '\u20ac') for i in locs]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What labels do you exactly want to be displayed on the x axis?

Comment: 0€, 5000€, 10000€, 15000€, 20000€

Comment: I am just trying to add an euro size to the label value